# Perform POST request with Lazarus

Tags: http, lazarus

How can I perform a POST request with Lazarus?

I found that it is possible to do using Indy for Lazarus, but the installation of Indy itself is a bit of a hassle, having to recompile and all. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use other library like [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/). There is `httpsend` unit with functions like `HttpPostURL()`, it also supports SSL/TLS. I used this library with both Delphi and FPC.

If you do not need to use SSL/TLS, proxy or other more complicated things then it is not very complicated to create your own HTTP simple client based on socket and many HTTP tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up installing Indy, as it also has more functionality, but will try Synapse soon.

Answer (score 0):

Using Indy with Lazarus is very easy, if you do not need the components in the palette but create them at run time.

Just add `<indy>/Lib/Core`, `<indy>/Lib/Protocols` and `<indy>/Lib/System` to the search path.

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays there is the fphttpclient unit supplied with FPC. So no need external libs/components to send POST, GET etc methods.